# Extracting email from text string in excel/google spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm looking to extract email addresses from text strings in Google Docs/Excel and email them automatically, where the content of the cells are currently unknown (until updated by user).

For example, they might read:

1. > Hi,
   >
   > My friend example@example.com.
   >
   > Thanks,
   >
   > Example Joe

*OR*

2. > You should ask
   >
   > example@example.co.uk

I've currently got this formula:

```
=IFERROR((LEFT(CELL,FIND("@",CELL)-1))&"@"&(regexextract(CELL,"@(.*)")))
```

It works for almost all cases, *except*

a) as in example 1, where someone puts a , or . at the end of the email

b) as in example 2, where the email starts on a new line, it comes in as eg.

> ask
>
> example@example.com

How might I adapt the formula to correct these?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For Google Spreadsheets

[Google Spreadsheets](https://www.google.com/intl/en/sheets/about/) has these cool already-builtin regex formulas

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244), [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292), [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

We use the first one to extract mail adresses. Put this formula in a Google Spreadsheet cell:

```
=iferror(Regexextract(A1;"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}");"")
```

- `A1` is the cell where the string to check (mail body in your case) should reside
- Complete formula consist of 2 parts. The inner part is the regex formula and the outer part is for error prevention
- [`Regexextract(A1,"\[A-z0-9._%+-\]+@\[A-z0-9.-\]+\.\[A-z\]{2,4}")`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) returns the mail address
- [`iferror(innerformula,"")`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) prevents `#N/A` when the regex formula wasn't able to return anything e.g no valid mail address was found

[image]

#### How does the regex pattern work?

> [A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+.[A-z]{2,4}

- `A-z` represents any character between an `A` and a `z`.
  Note the uppercase and lowercase. This way it's case-insensitive
- `0-9` represents any digit
- `._%+-` represent those signs itself
- `[ ]` represents a single character which is allowed inside the brackets
- Putting a `+` sign behind `[ ]` allows the previous pattern to be repeated infinitely
- `@` has no special meaning. It literally searches for a `@` sign
- `[A-z0-9.-]+` is the same as above. But `_%+` are not allowed behind a `@` sign this time
- `\.` searches for a single point. It has to be escaped with a preceeding `\` because `.` normally is a placeholder any character
- At last `[A-z]{2,4}` searches for 2,3 or 4 case-insensitive characters

#### Used ressources

- http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. One thought I had is that `{2, 4}` could be limiting because many upcoming TLDs like `.codes` exceed 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Excel.

Consider the following *User Defined Function* (UDF):

```
Public Function GetEmailAddy(Sin As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    If InStr(1, Sin, "@") = 0 Then
        GetEmailAddy = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    s = Replace(Sin, Chr(10), " ")
    s = Replace(s, Chr(13), " ")
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(s)
    ary = Split(s, " ")

    For Each a In ary
        If InStr(1, a, "@") > 0 Then
            GetEmailAddy = a
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=GetEmailAddy(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here are some examples:

[image]